# Dependent naming of XML element in Xml Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xsd-1.1

Assuming that I have this XML:

```
<parameters>
  <parameter type="string" isVisible="True" optional="False" id="DealerCode">
     <DealerCode>ABCDEF001</DealerCode>
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

I used a Xml-Schema generator to generate me a basic one. This results in this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="DealerCode" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="parameter">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="DealerCode"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="type"/>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="isVisible"/>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="optional"/>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="id"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="parameters">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="parameter"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The naming of the element **DealerCode** is dependent to the **identifier** of the **parameter** element. For example if the **parameter** has the **identifier** `ZIP`, the sub-element of **parameter** should also be named that way. How can I achieve this in the Xml-Schema?

Example:

```
<parameter type="string" isVisible="True" optional="False" id="DealerCode">
    <DealerCode>ABCDEF001</DealerCode>
</parameter>

<parameter type="string" isVisible="True" optional="False" id="ZIP">
    <ZIP>ABCDEF001</ZIP>
</parameter>
```

Comment: @lexicore XSD 1.1+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### XSD 1.0

Not possible.  Options:

1. Use `xs:any` and check out-of-band with respect to XSD.
2. Redesign your XML by replacing the generic `parameter` with the specific element it wraps:

   ```
   <DealerCode type="string" isVisible="True"
               optional="False">ABCDEF001</DealerCode>
   ```

### XSD 1.1

Possible using `xs:assert`:

```
      <xs:assert test="*/local-name() = @id"/>
```

Here it is in context of your complete XSD, which will successfully validate your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:element name="DealerCode" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="parameter">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="type"/>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="isVisible"/>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="optional"/>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="id"/>
      <xs:assert test="*/local-name() = @id"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="parameters">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="parameter" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you add a sample how I can achieve this using `xs:assert`, please?

Comment: Answer updated to show full XSD 1.1 `xs:assert` example.

Comment: This does not work, I used a validator and it gives me this error: `S4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The Content Of '#AnonType_parameter' Is Invalid. Element 'assert' Is Invalid, Misplaced, Or Occurs Too Often`

Comment: I will try the version for 1.0 first, because I noticed that Visual Studio only supports 1.0.

Comment: **It does work, but it requires XSD 1.1, [which you said you had](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929963/dependent-naming-of-xml-element-in-xml-schema/40931226?noredirect=1#comment69073527_40929963).**  That error indicates that your XSD processor is XSD 1.0.